# trying to subscribe to an observable using ngIf and it's going into a loop

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2

Here's the html for icon which is supposed to be displayed when the user is logged in:

```
<mat-icon class="logout-icon logout-spacer" *ngIf="(isLoggedIn() | async)" (click)="logout()" >exit_to_app</mat-icon>
```

The component for that icon looks like this

```
  isLoggedIn(){
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn().pipe(
      take(1),
      map((authState) => !!authState),
      tap(user =>{
        if (user){
          console.log("user found");
        } else {
          console.log("user not found");
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Also there is an Auth Service which has code that is displayed below which is backed by AngularFire library

```
isLoggedIn(){
    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(first());
  }
```

When I run the app in the developer console all I'm able to see is that "user not found" repeatedly getting displayed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: isLoggedIn()  returns a new observable every time it is getting called

Comment: What’s the possible fix for that?

Comment: how about `this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn().pipe(...)`?

Comment: That worked.  But now when someone logs in it does not auto update.  I thought observables were supposed to push the changes when subscribed to. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are using `first` then `take(1)` to make sure to unsubscribe automatically after the first value.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks guys!